# what is the time complexity in my code

Tags: time-complexity

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int T,i,sum,n;    //Here T is the test case
        scanf("%d",&T);
        while(T--)
        {
            scanf("%d",&n);
            sum=0;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                sum=sum+i;
            printf("%d\n",sum);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

If i give input of test case as `T=50` and `n=100`.
Which is correct : time complexity `O(n)=100` or time complexity `O(n)=100*50`.

Comment: Time complexity can't be strictly defined in cases where external party is involved with unknown/undefined execution time - in your case there is a need for user input. Consider the situation where the user doesn't provide input for a very long time or doesn't provide it at all.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) analysis is not specific to certain values. [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) , which is commonly expressed in Big-Oh , excludes coefficients and lower order terms. Here in your Code, The time complexity would be O(T*N). It will never ever be O(50*100) or O(100). There is no such notation. Any algorithm which runs in constant time (50*100 in your code) will be expressed as O(1).

In one liner, Time Complexity will never be a value, it'll be expressed as a function that depends on the input size.

Also, to have a clear understanding, I'd suggest you to go through this tutorial: [Time Complexity Analysis by MyCodeSchool](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI9HK8YPVBjElbLbI3ufctn)

Comment: Thanks for ans.Really , i have expressed that complexity O(n) or O(T*n).

Comment: @SKL O(T*N) !! But I still doubt that you got the idea of Big O notation and time complexity !! Please go through the below tutorial : https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI9HK8YPVBjElbLbI3ufctn